# ID this movie about rebels fighting high tech God

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction, fantasy

Around 3 years ago, I watched this movie. This is an old style movies. It was in English and had long duration (2 hours and more). Unfortunately I only remember the mid to near ending plot.

There are a group of rebels (perhaps slaves) attacking this high tech God. The rebel use primitive weapons while the god army using fighter jet, laser guns and other high tech weapon. The protagonist also use a gun (perhaps he is a mercenary) that shoot bullet rather than laser. This god protected by an army that using armor and mask. The god is human like. There is a strange creature too, like a rhino. So, maybe the war is not on Earth

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stargate, the film that spawned a franchise.

[image]

Comment: woah... so fast and yes, that's the masked god army that I remember

Comment: When you're done with the movie, be sure to check out SG-1, the TV show which followed. :)